# Not able to send client certificate over openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am trying to implement MSRP over TLS, which requires me to do TLS handshaking for msrp port, i.e 2855. At the time of handshaking server is requesting for client certificate as expected. At the client end I have generated the certificate and the private key,however i am unable to send the certificate. I am using Doubango stack to communicate with openssl.

"**SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(contexts[i], transport->tls.ca, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)**" is what I am using to try to set the certificate. I think it gets set properly, since it doesn't throw any error. However, no matter what i do , the certificate is never sent to the server. 
The Certificates Length is always 0.

Can anyone help me regarding this problem ? These are the steps I am following to generate the client certificate. 
https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344

My code to set the certificates is something like this :

```
#if HAVE_OPENSSL
    {
        int32_t i, ret;
        SSL_CTX* contexts[3] = { tsk_null };

        if(transport->tls.enabled){
            contexts[0] = transport->tls.ctx_client;
            contexts[1] = transport->tls.ctx_server;
        }

        TSK_DEBUG_INFO("ca = %s, pbk = %s, pvk = %s", ca, pbk, pvk);
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(contexts)/sizeof(contexts[0]); ++i){
            if(!contexts[i]){
                continue;
            }
            SSL_CTX_set_verify(contexts[i], transport->tls.verify ? (SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT) : SSL_VERIFY_NONE, tsk_null);
            TSK_DEBUG_INFO("tls.verify :%d",  transport->tls.verify);
            if(!tsk_strnullORempty(transport->tls.pbk) || !tsk_strnullORempty(transport->tls.pvk) || !tsk_strnullORempty(transport->tls.ca)){
                /* Sets Public key (cert) */
                if((ret = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(contexts[i], transport->tls.ca, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) != 1) {
                    TSK_DEBUG_ERROR("SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file failed [%d,%s]", ret, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), tsk_null));
                    return -3;
                }
                /*Sets the password of the private key*/
                if(!tsk_strnullORempty(ssl_password)){
                    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(contexts[i], (void*)ssl_password);
                }

                /* Sets Private key (cert) */
                if (!tsk_strnullORempty(transport->tls.pvk) && (ret = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(contexts[i], transport->tls.pvk, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) != 1) {
                    TSK_DEBUG_ERROR("SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file failed [%d,%s]", ret, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), tsk_null));
                    return -4;
                }
                /* Checks private key */
                if(!tsk_strnullORempty(transport->tls.pvk) && SSL_CTX_check_private_key(contexts[i]) == 0) {
                    TSK_DEBUG_ERROR("SSL_CTX_check_private_key failed [%d,%s]", ret, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), tsk_null));
                    return -5;
                }
                /* Sets trusted CAs and CA file */
                if(!tsk_strnullORempty(transport->tls.ca) && (ret = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(contexts[i], transport->tls.ca, /*tlsdir_cas*/tsk_null)) != 1) {
                   TSK_DEBUG_ERROR("SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations failed [%d, %s]", ret, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), tsk_null));
                   return -5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
#endif /* HAVE_OPENSSL */
```

Since I am not getting any of these errors, I am assuming that the certificates has been properly set. But still when server request for the certificates, the client fails to send it. i.e Certificates Length = 0.
Is there a way to peek into openssl if it is throwing any errors? Where can i get the openssl logs. ? 
Please help or my leaves wouldnt get approved :(

Comment: The certificate or one of its signing certificates has to be signed by one of the signers specified in the `CertificateRequest` message. If your certificate doesn't comply, it won't be sent.

Comment: Do you mean the CA in the certificateRequest message? I am getting Distinguished Names Length: 0 in the certificateRequest from the server.  Do you think that is the problem ??

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming.

Comment: @Scooby - As EJP said, YES. The server needs to advertise the DNs it accepts/uses for client certificate authorities. That triggers the client to send the certificate. To get the server to send the appropriate message, I believe it should call [SSL_CTX_use_certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html). Also, put your relevant code with the question; and not on GitHub, if possible.

Comment: I have modified my question including the relevant code. I have verified with a working set of certificates, but still no positive result seen.

Comment: If the server sends a zero length list of DNs, it still doesn't trust any CAs, so the client can't send any certificates. The problem is at the server end, as @jww stated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. However, as per RFC 4346 section 7.4.4, it mentions "If the certificate_authorities list is empty then the client MAY send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType, unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary."
Do you think it really is the reason ???

Comment: Update: I had a word with the server team. It seems that other clients work with exactly the same configuration. So looks to be an issue from client end only. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the **Certificate types** in `Crtificate Request` message. If your client certificate encryption doesn't match, then the client may not send certificate.